# Pub Serve & IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, dart-pub

How come when i launch an instance of a dart web application in IntelliJ community edition 14, it kicks off using the IntelliJ server, but also spins up a Pub server instance.

IntelliJ's server lives on port 63342, where as pub server lives on 56995. Shouldn't it just use the Pub server? Is the IntelliJ server proxying the pub Http Server, and if so what if any are the implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ proxies from its HTTP server to pub.

This lets them do some deeper introspection for better IDE support, such as being able to monitor HTTP requests, use a built-in REST client and display HTTP requests / responses for API debugging, and probably some other integrations I can't think of off the top of my head.

It's probably more work *not* use their current infrastructure, so why bother?